# Can I take control of some WebForm from the external?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have some WebForms, such as `First.ascx.cs`, `Second.ascx.cs`, `Third.ascx.cs` and so on!

Well, I'd like to call a function (let's say, `startFunction()`) at the PreInit stage, and another one (let's say, `endFunction()`) and the PreRender stage, for EACH context.

So:

```
startFunction();
... First.ascx.cs PageLoad execution...
endFunction();

startFunction();
... Second.ascx.cs PageLoad execution...
endFunction();

startFunction();
... Third.ascx.cs PageLoad execution...
endFunction();
```

without write the same start/end function and copy and paste for each context I need to control. Is there a good strategy with .NET (3.5) and WebForms?

Comment: ascx are not webforms are usercontrols. I don't understand if you want to attach to usercontrols event or to the container webpage events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheritance!

Create a basecontrol where you attach to those events and then derive from it.

MarkzzzClass .cs

```
public abstract class MarkzzzClass : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
//do something
}
```

BaseControl.cs:

```
public abstract class BaseControl : MarkzzzClass 
{
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        EndFunction();
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        StartFunction();
        base.OnInit(e);
    }
}
```

First.ascx.cs:

```
public partial class First : BaseControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Inheritance with User Controls? Uhm, can you give to me an example?

Comment: @markzzz inheritance can be used everywhere... it is the base of OOP.

Comment: the problem is that I already extend a class in my `First.cs`: `public partial class First : MarkzzzClass`

Comment: @markzzz  you can put an other abstract class in the middle. I updated the example

Comment: Yeah, I thought to it, but I have to review the whole system! Anyway, I think I will do this way! Thank you.

Comment: Well, what about this question? "I don't understand if you want to attach to usercontrols event or to the container webpage events". What do you mean with webpage events?

Comment: @markzzz I did not understand if you wanted to attach to Page.PreRender or UserControl.PreRender

Comment: Uhm, what's the main differences? I think Page must be called only 1 time each function, on UserControl each time for each control, right? The code you post is for each UserControl I guess...

Comment: @markzzz yes, it is. But PreInit event does not exist on usercontrol